# TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN event does not fire

Tags: actionscript

I have the following code for ios app,

```
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
        var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        mySprite.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
        mySprite.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);
        mySprite.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
        mySprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x336699);
        mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
        mySprite.x = 100;
        mySprite.y = 100;
        var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
        myTextField.y = 200;
        addChild(mySprite);
        addChild(myTextField);
        myTextField.text = "Wait";

        function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            myTextField.text = "onClick";
        }

        function onPan(e:MouseEvent):void {
            myTextField.text = "onPan";
        }

        function onSwipe(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
            myTextField.text = "onSwipe";
        }

        function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
            myTextField.text = "onZoom";
        }
```

When I test the app on itouch, everything works except onPan. It seems the TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN event never fires no matter what I do. When I move my finger while pressiing down, the onSwipe gets called. If I comment out the event listener for TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE then nothing gets called when I move my finger while pressing down.

Am I doing the pan gesture wrong? What is the difference between TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN and TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE gestures?

Thank you very much for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN works with two fingers.

Try it and you will check that when you press the screen with two fingers and move, the object will start panning.

Use instead MouseEvent.MOUSEMOVE

EDIT: Look this sentence from one Manual:

> When a user grabs an object with two fingers and drags it, the TransformGesture
>   Event.GESTURE_PAN event is triggered and the onGesturePan method is called. Within the
>   onGesturePan method, the offsetX and offsetY values of this event are written to the
>   text property of the TextArea component. Adding the event’s offsetX and offsetY values
>   sets the object’s x and y to move the object across the stage.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Domoindal, do you mean use MouseEvent.MOUSEMOVE will enable the single finger pan?

Answer (score 0):

Pan only worked for me when I did double-finger press and move.  I cant find a proper description of what these different gestures actually are, but that's what it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

`function onPan(e:MouseEvent):` must be  `onPan(e:TransformGestureEvent)`